# Non-Latex accents in matplotlib titles

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, diacritics

I want to use the default sans-serif font in matplotlib to write the plot title, which has to contain an "ä", german a-umlaut. If found that usually in python this is done with declaring `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning. Then however I get an error when using a non-ascii character within a plot. Other than that, I only found the solution to use `$\"a$`, with gives me an italic LaTeX letter. Using `\mathrm` gives me the non-italic LaTeX font. Is there no way to do that with the default matplotlib font, which I use for all other text in this plot?

Comment: It might help if you provide a minimal working example reporducing your problem.

Comment: I don't think there would be any need for an example in this case. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use unicode strings:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title(u"Übergrößenträger")
plt.show()
```

(Note the `u`)

Comment: `u` is only needed if you use python2.